# Set Related Entity Id on Detached POCO Proxy

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, poco

I have a detached POCO proxy from EF 4.0 (detached meaning the ObjectContext has disposed).

I have a property MyRelatedEntityId which is a FK for the navigation property MyRelatedEntity.

As it happens, I know what value I want to set for MyRelatedEntityId, so I try to set it manually....but the detached POCO proxy throws an exception that the ObjectContext has already disposed.

How can I do this or is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must turn off lazy loading. I think once you set FK property, dynamic proxy will try to load related entity and it fails because of disposed context.

Edit:

I just checked this problem because as you mentioned lazy loading should not be triggered. The problem is autogenerated code which uses Fixup methods to set up a bidirectional relation. If you loaded previous related entity and you change FK it sets related entity to null. This triggers the fixup method which tries to remove the current entity from the previous related entity's childs. If you didn't load them before disposing context you will get an exception. Just try to debug the code including generated one.

The solution is either:

- Turn off lazy loading for this scenario
- Remove navigation collection from related entity
- Modify T4 template so it doesn't generate fixup methods

Comment: I don't want to turn off lazy loading. I'm not trying to set the navigation property, just the actual FK Id

Comment: I added code that turns off lazy loading once the ObjectContext is disposing...but leaves it on until then.

Answer (score 1):

Did you detatch the entity before the ObjectContext was disposed? Have you tried setting it after attaching the entity to a new ObjectContext?

Comment: Disposing the ObjectContext should leave all entities in a detached state, no? I don't want to re-attach the entity yet...just to set the Id for the FK.

Comment: I'm not sure that entities attached to a disposed ObjectContext get automatically detached, will have to verify